# How to change IE to Non-compatibility mode without the meta-tag

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I need to change IE browsers to use the latest mode, 9 or 10, but I do not have access to the header so I cannot put in the tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">`. I did use DOM Manipulation to add the tag to the beginning of the header tag, but since that part of the page already loads before the jquery can put it in there, it does not affect IE. Is there a way to change the mode, or to reload the header only once so it changes the mode its in.

Comment: use php's header() function

Answer (score 0):

How is the page hosted, do you have access to the web server configuration?
If so, you can set X-UA-Compatible as a response header.
E.g. configuring Apache would be something like this:

```
<IfModule headers_module>
    Header set X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge 
</IfModule>
```

and could be done in either Apache's httpd.conf or possibly in a .htaccess file if AllowOverride is on.

If you don't have access to web server configuration, you could try to set the same header from whatever language/framework you use to serve the pages.

Comment: My company uses the Web Builder Ingenuix, and I no access to any configuration. Most of the people who publish webpages have very little, if any, web experience, so they restrict almost everything to prevent them from messing things up.